# printf() prints whole char matrix

Tags: c, matrix, char, printf

As marked in the code, the first `printf()` rightfully prints only the i-th line of the matrix. But outiside the loop, both `printf()` and `strcat()` act on the whole matrix from i-th line on as a single-lined string. This means that

```
printf("%s\n",m_cfr[0])
```

will print whole matrix, but m_cfr[i] will print whole matrix from the i-th line on. `char* string` is a single lined string with no spaces.

```
trasp(char* string)
{
    int row = strlen(string) / 5;
    char m[row][5];
    char m_cfr[row][5];
    char cfr[row*5];

    memset(cfr, 0, row * 5);

    int key[5] = {3, 1, 2, 0, 4};
    int k      = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < row ; i++)
    {
        strncpy(m[i], string + k, 5);

        m[i][5] = '\0';
        k      += 5;    
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < row ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++)
        {
            m_cfr[i][key[j]] = m[i][j];
        }
        m_cfr[i][5] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", m_cfr[i]);  //--->prints only line i
    }    
    printf("%s\n", m_cfr[0]); //prints whole matrix    
    strcat(cfr, m_cfr[0]);   //concatenates whole matrix       
    printf("%s\n", cfr);
}
```

Comment: printf prints characters until the first 0-byte occurs.

Comment: `m_cfr[i][5]='\0';` You're writing to the sixth element when there are only five.

Comment: every line of the matrix is null terminated as you can see

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sir, I think OP want to know "_why_ `//prints whole matrix`" :-)

Comment: When OP should ask that question instead of simply stating a fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, your array definition is

```
char m_cfr[row][5];
```

while you're accessing

```
 m_cfr[i][5] = '\0';
 /*       ^
          | 
          there is no 6th element
 */
```

You're facing [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Out-of-bound memory access causes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Maybe you want to change the null-terminating statement to

```
m_cfr[i][4] = '\0'; //last one is null
```

Comment: What? Since when is it possible to know who voted on an answer?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Err..not for vote, I thanked for the edit. :-) [And don't worry, still, you can't know who has voted, even in case of upvote] :P

Answer (score 0):

`%s` expects a `char*` and prints everything until it encounters a `\0`. So,

```
printf("%s\n", m_cfr[i]);
printf("%s\n",m_cfr[0]);
strcat(cfr,m_cfr[0]);
```

All exhibit Undefined Behavior as `m_cfr[i]`,`m_cfr[0]` and `m_cfr[0]` are `char`s and not `char*`s and `%s` as well as both the arguments of `strcat` expects a `char*`. Also, as [SouravGhosh points out](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28431354/printf-prints-whole-char-matrix/28431439#28431439), using

```
m_cfr[i][5] = '\0';
```

And

```
m[i][5] = '\0';
```

Are wrong.

To fix the former issue, use

```
printf("%s\n", &m_cfr[i]);
printf("%s\n",m_cfr);
strcat(cfr,&m_cfr[0]);
```

To print the whole string and concatenate the two strings in the arguments of `strcat` or if you wanted to print just the `chars`, use

```
printf("%c\n", m_cfr[i]);
printf("%c\n",m_cfr[0]);
```

As for the latter issue, use

```
char m[row][5]={{0}};
char m_cfr[row][5]={{0}};
```